# Is there a way to install "starbase" for Enthought Canopy Python?

Tags: python, hbase, enthought, canopy

I have Enthought Canopy Python 3.5 on my Windows and am trying to install the "starbase" package into it. However, starbase is not in the Package Manager in Enthought Canopy. Is there a workaround that would allow me to install starbase?

I have tried installing it in Windows command prompt but no luck either. (see attached screenshot)

[image]

[image]

Comment: Make sure pip is installed on your computer. You can follow the instruction here https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installing/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open a Canopy Command Prompt (either from the Canopy Tools menu or from the Start menu)

Now pip will be available.

For cautions about possible dependency conflicts, see this article from the Enthought Knowledge Base: https://support.enthought.com/hc/en-us/articles/115001478186-Installing-packages-into-Canopy-2-User-Python-from-the-OS-command-line